# How to store and update score in the game?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

How can I create a function and make it work so that it stores the win case every time user or computer wins?

How can I create a function and make it work so that it stores the win case every time user or computer wins?How can I create a function and make it work so that it stores the win case every time user or computer wins?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Rock Paper Scissors Tutorial</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Computer Choice: <span id="computer-choice"></span></h2>
    <h2>Your Choice: <span id="user-choice"></span></h2>
    <h2>Result: <span id="result"></span></h2>
    <button id="rock">rock</button>
    <button id="paper">paper</button>
    <button id="scissors">scissors</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Reload Page" onClick="document.location.reload(true)">
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="results">
        <div>
          You
          <span class="result-score">0</span>
        </div>
        <div data-final-column>
          Computer
          <span class="result-score">0</span>
   </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

--------------------
js

const computerChoiceDisplay = document.getElementById('computer-choice')
const userChoiceDisplay = document.getElementById('user-choice')
const resultDisplay = document.getElementById('result')
const possibleChoices = document.querySelectorAll('button')
const computerScoreSpan = document.querySelector('[data-computer-score]')
const yourScoreSpan = document.querySelector('[data-your-score]')
let userChoice
let computerChoice
let result

possibleChoices.forEach(possibleChoice => possibleChoice.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  userChoice = e.target.id
  userChoiceDisplay.innerHTML = userChoice
  generateComputerChoice()
  getResult()
}))
// ------
// function incrementScore(scoreSpan) {
//     if (yourWinner) incrementScore(yourScoreSpan)
//     if (computerWinner) incrementScore(computerScoreSpan)
//     scoreSpan.innerText = parseInt(scoreSpan.innerText) + 1
//   }

// --------
function generateComputerChoice() {
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1 // or you can use possibleChoices.length
  
  if (randomNumber === 1) {
    computerChoice = 'rock'
  }
  if (randomNumber === 2) {
    computerChoice = 'scissors'
  }
  if (randomNumber === 3) {
    computerChoice = 'paper'
  }
  computerChoiceDisplay.innerHTML = computerChoice
}

function getResult() {
  if (computerChoice === userChoice) {
    result = 'its a draw!'
  }
  if (computerChoice === 'rock' && userChoice === "paper") {
    result = 'you win!'
  }
  if (computerChoice === 'rock' && userChoice === "scissors") {
    result = 'you lost!'
  }
  if (computerChoice === 'paper' && userChoice === "scissors") {
    result = 'you win!'
  }
  if (computerChoice === 'paper' && userChoice === "rock") {
    result = 'you lose!'
  }
  if (computerChoice === 'scissors' && userChoice === "rock") {
    result = 'you win!'
  }
  if (computerChoice === 'scissors' && userChoice === "paper") {
    result = 'you lose!'
  }
  resultDisplay.innerHTML = result
}
```

Comment: Why do you repeat what you say? Why do you repeat what you say? Why do you repeat what you say? Why not use that space to actually explain what "storing" means, and how it should use the stored values, and what you have researched on the subject (you should have encountered cookies, localStorage, server application, ...etc).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question is not clear.  And repeating the same unclear question multiple times doesn't make it more clear.  Please elaborate on what you are trying to ask.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: I am really sorry, but I tried adding space and still it says "most of your comments are codes please add more"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for starters your code is really inefficient and messy, and I wouldn't definitely recommend re-starting. But if you want to keep the code you already have, to make the score counter you don't need a function, just add to the score based of the result in the result function.

Here's the updated HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Rock Paper Scissors Tutorial</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Computer Choice: <span id="computer-choice"></span></h2>
    <h2>Your Choice: <span id="user-choice"></span></h2>
    <h2>Result: <span id="result"></span></h2>
    <button id="rock">rock</button>
    <button id="paper">paper</button>
    <button id="scissors">scissors</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Reload Page" onClick="document.location.reload(true)">
    <br>
    <br>
        <div id="ys">
          You: 0
        </div>
        <div id="cs">
          Computer: 0
                </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and your javascript code

```
const computerChoiceDisplay = document.getElementById('computer-choice')
const userChoiceDisplay = document.getElementById('user-choice')
const resultDisplay = document.getElementById('result')
const possibleChoices = document.querySelectorAll('button')
const cs_t = document.getElementById("cs");
const ps_t = document.getElementById("ys");
let userChoice
let computerChoice
let result

var cs = 0;
var ps = 0;

possibleChoices.forEach(possibleChoice => possibleChoice.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  userChoice = e.target.id
  userChoiceDisplay.innerHTML = userChoice
  generateComputerChoice()
  getResult()
}))
// ------


// --------
function generateComputerChoice() {
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1 // or you can use possibleChoices.length
  
  if (randomNumber === 1) {
    computerChoice = 'rock'
  }
  if (randomNumber === 2) {
    computerChoice = 'scissors'
  }
  if (randomNumber === 3) {
    computerChoice = 'paper'
  }
  computerChoiceDisplay.innerHTML = computerChoice
}

function getResult() {
  if (computerChoice === userChoice) {
    result = 'its a draw!'
  }
  if (computerChoice === 'rock' && userChoice === "paper") {
    result = 'you win!'
  }
  if (computerChoice === 'rock' && userChoice === "scissors") {
    result = 'you lost!'
  }
  if (computerChoice === 'paper' && userChoice === "scissors") {
    result = 'you win!'
  }
  if (computerChoice === 'paper' && userChoice === "rock") {
    result = 'you lose!'
  }
  if (computerChoice === 'scissors' && userChoice === "rock") {
    result = 'you win!'
  }
  if (computerChoice === 'scissors' && userChoice === "paper") {
    result = 'you lose!'
  }
    if(result == 'you win!'){
        ps += 1
    }
    else if(result == 'you lose!'){
        console.log("ok2")
        cs += 1
    }
    else{
        cs += 1
        ps += 1
    }
    
    cs_t.innerHTML = ("Computer: " + cs);
    ps_t.innerHTML = ("You: " + ps);
  resultDisplay.innerHTML = result
}
```

also you do not need to put span tags in everything, it's a really bad way of doing it.

Comment: Thank you much and I am sorry about the messy code and repeating 100 times. I am just trying to understand everything but it seems like thats the problem. I have to learn one at a time and take my time to understand the code.

Comment: It works but now even the game is draw the result numbers are incrementing. UPDATE: I think i figured out by tweaking the statements. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

from what I understand you want to save the winner of the game somewhere so you can check it later right?

Well, maybe you can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage);

With that, all you gotta do is take the result and store them on localStorage, like this:

```
localStorage.setItem('result', result);
```

and for get the result from localStorage, you can save it on a variable:

```
const checkResult = localStorage.getItem('result') || null
```

in that way if do not have any results on localStorage, checkResult will return null;